# DynamoDB query on GSI returns null with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query dynamo table using global index but it is returning null for some reason. I do have a record that I can query on from console but not working with node js sdk.

heres my code:

```
try {
    var queryParams = {
      IndexName: "gsi1-index",
      KeyConditionExpression: "gsi1 = :gsi1",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":gsi1": userEmail,
      },
      TableName: usersTable,
    };
    await ddb.query(queryParams, (err, userData) => {
      // if (err || userData.Count === 0)
      //   return res.status(400).json({ data: "No information was found" });
      return res.status(200).json(userData);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err);
  }
```

I don't know what am i doing wrong exactly? googled everywhere but my code is exactly the same as the others and all the examples

Comment: Can you update the question and add the key schema of the table, the GSI and an example of the item you're supposed to retrieve?

Comment: When you say "it's not working", are you getting an error, empty results, something else?

Comment: @Andre.IDK gsi is the name of the index /attribute in my table. This is the exact code that I am running

Comment: @SethGeoghegan I am getting null back

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a full code example, but I'll venture a guess.  I'm assuming you are running this code in an async lambda using the DDB DocumentClient API.

The problem appears to be that you are using `await` and callbacks together.

```
   await ddb.query(queryParams, (err, userData) => {
      return res.status(200).json(userData);
    });
```

Try this instead

```
let data = await ddb.query(queryParams).promise();
// do something with data
```

Comment: So heres the issue exactly. I am was missing an IAM role on the index table itself. I forgot that gsi creates a new table and i needed an iam role for that. your way helped me debug the issue to be honest! please update the answer so I can mark it as correct. Also which way would you rather go? the call back or the let data = promise?